# Bootstrap 3: Accordion body collapses before content is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue with accordion collapse. It used to work fine before, but broke at some point in time and I am not entirely sure if this is related to Bootstrap 3 upgrade. I re-wrote half of the project recently, so there is a possibility that it is something I've accidentally done.

I create an pretty large accordion with KnockoutJS. It populates the groups/panels and they open as expected, but when i try to collapse a group, content of the group shifts to the top of the enclosing container, then the group collapses, but the content of it still lingers for about a second, until it finally disappears and I get the expected result - collapsed accordion.

```
<div id="accordion" class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">Title Here</a>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Content Here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried using the example below from Bootstrap documentation to rule out the problem with my CSS and using only theirs, but that produced the same result. Content of an accordion group lingers for about a second while the actual group is already collapsed.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried reducing the content of the accordion group to a single string of text. The issue still remained.

Any idea how to work around this?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see it happening, see the bootstrap example I modified at http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/ogxOJY. Do you perhaps have an codepen or jsFiddle?

Comment: @ckuijjer: I figured it out just now. It is Bootstrap 3 related. Well, let me rephrase. The admin template I am using is not compatible with Bootstrap 3, unfortunately. Had to roll back to 2.2.8 for now. Thank you for taking a look though.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you need to downgrade back to an older bootstrap version. If you use any of their demo's as a start. You should start with an upgraded version of the demo/template before upgrading the framework. Usually the template is more backward compatible than the bootstrap css. It's pretty tedious.

Comment: I just saw, that you figured that out... fail. :)